# Tournament Scheduling Algorithm Starting Point

Tags: performance, algorithm, scheduling, computation, tournament

This is a question about performance and best placement of matchups within a schedule that contains dates/times/locations.

Starting with a schedule grid (date/time/locations) in place and all matchups generated what is the best place to start with scheduling those matchups in the grid.

#1 Iterate the grid by date/time/location and find the first game that matches that spot.

#2 Iterate the matchup list and determine the best place for it to go in the schedule grid.

Which one would give the best possible results along with performance?

Answer (score 1):

I think algorithm suitable for such scheduling is n-chromatic graph coloring algorithm.
This should give you a start to think about the logic you need to implement.

(IMHO 2nd option is better as it resembles with above graph coloring algo.)